# css selector with specific sibling

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Using a CMS that generates the following:

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
 <li>content 1</li>
 <li>content 2</li>
</ul>
<ul class="list-unstyled">
 <li>
  <span>content 3</span>
 </li>
 <li>
  <h2>content 4</h2>
 </li>
</ul>
```

I would like to css select "content 4".
There is many `<ul>` tags with class "list-unstyled".
Is there a way to select `.list-unstyled > li > h2` where the li have a sibling `li > span`

This is nessesary so that I dont select more than just content 4. There is a possibility that there is a `.list-unstyled > li > h2` in another place but without the sibling `li > span`

Hope I made myself clear

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a way to select `.list-unstyled > li > h2` where the li have a sibling `li > span`

No, since you can't express a `li` that has a `span` child in a selector for the purposes of the sibling relationship. See [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

See if you can alter the output of your CMS somehow to generate the necessary classes for your elements.

Answer (score 0):

you mean something like

```css
ul > li + li > h2{color:green}
```

```html
<ul class="list-unstyled">
 <li>content 1</li>
 <li>content 2</li>
</ul>
<ul class="list-unstyled">
 <li>
  <span>content 3</span>
 </li>
 <li>
  <h2>content 4</h2>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Basically CSS can't look upwards.

You may want to look into javascript and dom element properties for a more customized approach based on conditional testing;
but maybe it's easier to change markup:)

Comment: No because this doesn't account for the fact that the preceding li has a span child.

Comment: @BoltClock well if the h2 tag doesn't give enough specificity you're right

Comment: ... what? What does the h2 have to do with the span?

Comment: nothing , it's just like selecting through `ul > li > h2` , but with some extra specific conditions (none of which check if a sibling li has a span...)